# Not able to post large JSON data to Web API using Angular 4 app

Tags: jquery, json, angular, typescript, redux

I want to export 100k records for that i have to send large json data to server. 
Code:

```
 public export(payload: string) {
    let headersObj = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let body: record;
    var objectToSend = JSON.stringify(payload);      

     return this.http
        .post(EXPORT,
        objectToSend,{ headers: headersObj, observe: "response", responseType: "arraybuffer" }).timeout(1000000)
        .map((response: any) => {

        });
}
```

I am able to post json data with record count upto 50k to 60k. Above that the server call is failing.

> Browser is getting crashed.

Comment: Do you have control of the server code? Would you be able to split the HTTP post call in to multiple calls?

Comment: Yes i have control to server side. How to do that (split) because payload is the only one parameter that is getting passed to server.

Comment: This may make you understand the cause - https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/6bfade6431e9ffb7fe88

Comment: I believe you can modify the maximum size of the acceptable payload for a request on the sever. This is to prevent the server from rejecting the request. But depending on your API it might make more sense to make 2 or more HTTP post requests, each containing a portion of the JSON payload you are wanting to send.

Comment: @LukeStoward can you give some example of it?

Comment: Not really, as I have no idea what your payload is, what you server technology is, or what the endpoint is doing with the request.

Comment: payload is json data(Table  rows), i am using .net core 2.0 web api